# Unable to call a pl sql function contained in a package

Tags: plsql

I have code like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schema_name.abc AS

FUNCTION f1
RETURN CLOB AS
    BEGIN
       <some task>
    END;

PROCEDURE p1
    BEGIN
        f1(<param>);
    END;
END abc;
```

This package runs fine when we call `abc.p1(<parameter>)`
Now when I try to just run the function of a package in an anonymous block

```
DECLARE
temp_clb CLOB;

BEGIN
   temp_clb := <schema_name>.abc.f1(<parameter>);
END;
```

it gives me

```
PLS-00302: component 'f1'must be declared
```

Comment: You posted only the package BODY. How about the package specifications? Is the function declared there?

Comment: I get it as the function was not declared in the package specification rather the procedure which was calling it was contained in the package specification. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to **declare** your function in the Package SPEC. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE schema_name.abc AS
   FUNCTION f1
   RETURN CLOB;
```

Comment: I get it as the function was not declared in the package specification rather the procedure which was calling it was contained in the package specification. Thanks